# Syntax for interpolating planes (Python)

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, plane

I have a function D(x,y,z) in which I want to evaluate (via interpolation) planes within the z, y, and z axis. i.e. I want the output of my interpolations to be a 2D plane holding one of the values fixed, D(x,y,0) for example.

I have created an interpolating function via scipy using some given values of D, D_values, for my input values of x,y,z.

```
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator as rgi   
D_interp=rgi((x_positions,y_positions,z_positions), D_values)
```

Now I can get any point interpolated by just calling

```
D_interpolated=D_interp(xi,yi,zi)
```

I understand how I can evaluate individual points from this, but how would I interpolate a plane? For example, in my case, D_values is of size 345x155x303 and I want to interpolate 345x155 planes all along the z axis corresponding to the x and y input values, at z=0, z=1, z=2, etc.

My attempt at a solution is to feed in the x_positions, y_positions vectors individually into D_interp keeping z fixed, but this just gets me a set of D values evaluated at specific positions, rather than organized into a grid like the planar output I'd actually like. Syntax doesn't allow me to call something like

```
Plane=D_interp(x_positions,y_positions,0)
```

so I was not quite sure about the syntax of calling this function to have planar output.

any help appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach to combining multiple arrays with different sizes corresponding to different dimensions in numpy and scipy is to use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Here is a sample problem to illustrate the application:

```
x_positions = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
y_positions = np.linspace(-10, 10, 201)
z_positions = np.linspace(-5, 5, 101)
D_values = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x_positions[:, None, None] * y_positions[:, None] / 100) + np.cos(2 * np.pi * y_positions[:, None] * z_positions / 50)
```

This is similar to the `D_values` array you describe in your problem, where each of the bins in the different directions correspond to the `*_positions` arrays. I used broadcasting to turn `x_positions` into a `(101, 1, 1)`-shaped array, `y_positions` into a `(201, 1)`-shaped array and left `z_positions` as a `(101,)`-shaped array. The result is that `D_values` is a `(101, 201, 101)`-shaped array. The reshaped versions of the input arrays did not copy any data!

You can call your interpolator using the same idea that I used to create a sample `D_values`.

```
D_interp = rgi((x_positions, y_positions, z_positions), D_values)
```

Let's say you want to fix `z = 0`. All that scipy requires is that the inputs broadcast together. Scalars broadcast with everything, so you can just do

```
x_interp = np.linspace(0.05, 0.95, 200)
y_interp = np.linspace(-9.95, 9.95, 400)
z_interp = 0
D_xy_interp = D_interp((x_interp[:, None], y_interp, z_interp))
```

The advantage to doing this over creating a mesh is that you don't have to copy any data around and create extra 200x400 input arrays. Another advantage is that you have better control over the output. In this case, `D_xy_interp` has shape `(len(x_interp), len(y_interp))`. That's because in general, the shape of the output will be the broadcasted shape of the input. You can see that when we created `D_values`, and you can see it here. Since `0` is a scalar, it does not contribute to the shape. But I could also make a `(400, 200)` shaped array instead:

```
D_interp((x_interp, y_interp[:, None], z_interp))
```

Or even a `(100, 4, 100, 2)` shaped array:

```
D_interp((x_interp.reshape(-1, 2), y_interp.reshape(-1, 4, 1, 1), z_interp))
```

In either case, let's verify that the interpolator did it's job. We can compare the interpolated values to a much finer sampling of the function that created `D_values`:

```
D_xy_values = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x_interp[:, None] * y_interp / 100) + np.cos(2 * np.pi * y_interp * z_interp / 50)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
ax.plot_surface(x_interp[:, None], y_interp, D_xy_interp, label='Interp')
ax.plot_surface(x_interp[:, None], y_interp, D_xy_values, label='Values')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

At the moment it doesn't look like you can add legends to 3D plots:

[image].

The two plots are virtually indistinguishable. With the default color cycler, you will see the surface chance from blue to orange as you rotate it. Here is an analytical verification:

```
>>> np.sqrt(np.mean((D_xy_values - D_xy_interp)**2))
4.707625623185639e-05
```

Comment: Nice solution! And with `cube = interp((x_interp[:, None, None], y_interp[:, None], z_interp))` you can get multiple planes at once, if you don't mind that `z` is the last dimension of the output `cube`.

Comment: @Markus. Exactly. This is a general approach, which lets you slice and dice in more ways than one.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Can you explain why you needed to do x_interp[:, None] but didn't have to do the same for y_interp?

Comment: @hex93. It's all in the broadcasting page I linked. An index of `None` means to add a new unit dimension, which can broadcast against any shape. So if `x_interp.shape` is `(X,)` then `x_interp[:, None].shape` is `(X, 1)`. You could add a new dimension to `y_interp` thus `y_interp[None, :]`, but it's not necessary because broadcasting lines up dimensions to the right. In other words, all necessary leading ones are assumed anyway.

Comment: Thanks, the broadcasting page unfortunately goes to a 503 (service temporarily unavailable) error. 

Sorry your comment was very helpful but I'm still struggling to understand specifically what broadcasting does. Is it right to say that it will automatically assume the rank of all inputs is the highest rank of any input? Am I right that I can call the `z=0` plane with `D_interp((x_interp[:, None], y_interp, 0))`, the `y=0` plane with `D_interp((x_interp[:, None], 0, z_interp))` , and the `x=0` plane with `D_interp((0, y_interp[:,None, z_interp))` ?

Comment: @hex93. It's back up for me. Try again. Broadcasting is the idea that an operation can be applied to multiple dimensions if they either match or are 1 between two arrays.